# ModX: Duplicate entire site for testing new template?

Tags: modx

I want to test a new template & CSS for a site redesign.

Is there any "easy" way to do this?

I'm not familiar with Contexts. Theoretically I'd like to duplicate the main context, then experiment with it ... but how can I access it without having to mess around with subdomains, htaccess, etc.?

Is there any way to "go" to a 2nd context via simple URL?

E.g., say our "live" site is at "www.foo.com" ... I want to duplicate that context, call it "testing", then be able to navigate to the root of the 2nd context with "www.foo.com/testing".

So the duplicate of "foo.com/container/page" would be at "foo.com/testing/container/page" in the 2nd context.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a completely separate ModX instance. Contexts serve a different purpose.

On this instance you can edit your existing templates, TVs, chunks, etc. without affecting your master instance, overloading it, nor putting it at risk (specially if it's production). Once the test instance is ready you can easily copy over those edits to your master instance.

In summary the steps would be the following:

1. Create a new ModX instance and [copy data (DataBase & files) from the master instance](http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/moving-your-site-to-a-new-server).
2. Configure, edit and test your new ModX instance: test.domain.com
3. Copy over the edits to the master instance following the same guide on step 1.

If you want to have more control over what gets imported and exported on steps 1 and 3 you can use the tool [Teleport](https://github.com/modxcms/teleport) and check out this [video tutorial](http://vimeo.com/87146819).

If you use [ModX Cloud](https://modxcloud.com/) steps 1 and 3 are easier to accomplish.